# browserify: get query string from current url

Tags: node.js, npm, browserify

For my code compiled by browserify, I cannot find a way to get current URL (by windows.location.href) as well as the corresponding query string. Does anyone know how? Thanks!

Comment: It's `window.location.href`. `window`, not `windows`. Whether or not you are using browserify shouldn't matter.

Comment: Sorry, my typo here, I use `window.location.href` and `ReferenceError: window is not defined` prompted during compile

Comment: I don't see why browserify would error on that. You might want to try `global` instead of `window`. Are you sure this error happens when you bundle the code? Are you trying to *run* the code in Node.js by any chance (that wouldn't work of course)?

Comment: Thanks @felix-kling, with your comments, I found that the code I cannot compile is due to the validation result by other script before the code is built. It is not an issue of browserify.